# Count rows with specific criteria in columns Excel by month

Tags: excel

I have a list of actions in Excel, sorted by a couple of criterias by column, the 'key' or ID being the date it was added to the list.  The relevant criterias are date in the A column, location, and category.

I want to follow-up on the actions listed by the criterias monthly. I have not gotten this function to work however, even after trying a couple of different functions. So basically I want to count the number of rows in column A (starting from row X, since the first columns are not included), that include the specific criteria from columns B and C. So I want to count the different categories separately, and each category by location.

The list of possibilities in B and C comes from a list that is used in data validation, so that the categories and locations are given in drop-down menus.
The follow-up is also on its own tab in the spreadsheet, and the list criterias on its own.

What I have tried so far is e.g. sumproduct with (--), countifs with the column and the expression (MONTH(A:A)=1) and (B:B;"criteriaX").
All of these give me a #VALUE!-error.

Comment: Please include an example of your data. In what format is date represented for example? What is the value of "criteriaX" and what is the content of column B?

Comment: The date is in the date-serialformat, i.e. in my local version today is viewed as 1.2.2017 but the serial value is whatever corresponsd to that. Content of column B can be either "LabA", "LabB", etc (no spaces between). Criteria X is a longer string of text, such as "Idea", "Accident", "HSE Observation" etc. 

So both of the criteria is text strings, while the date is in serial format.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the limited information you have supplied.  Please read the help file for this forum for  information on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It would certainly be much easier for someone who wants to help to cut and paste an example, or download a sample file, than to reconstruct something from the description in your comment.